# Tool is delaying output in eclipse plugin developemnt

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jobs

I am developing plugin for eclipse. It will run my clang tool. In clang tool i am writing simple pass to check that every case and default statement must have the break statement.

I am running my clang tool using process builder. 
I am using job API to run my tool and Display class to print the error.

when i run my plugin i am facing some issue.
Let say i commented my break statement of one of the case or default statement , it should print error in console that every case and default statement must have the break statement.
it is printing error  after i type something else or some space or trying to uncomment after my comment .
similarly when i do uncomment , it should not print the error , but it is printing , but again when i type something or some space or trying to comment , error disappear.

following is the link of my code

https://github.com/sunilsarode/eclipse_plugin/blob/master/ccchecker/src/ccchecker/handlers/SampleHandler.java

following image show the first case not printing error on my eclipse console on which i am developing a plugin .
[image]
and this shows that second case printing error on my eclipse console on which i am developing a plugin .
[image]

any help in this ?

**EDIT:**
I want my plugin-in to output something on console view (not on development console ) or some dot kind of thing on the gutter of the text editor and when i click or hover on that dot , i want to show some popup with error message.

I tried to print message on console view by crating console using this link https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F
 it works , but new problem is , i lost focus from text editor to console that i have created and because of this i am unable to test the problem i mentioned in question.

sorry too much i am expecting.

Following image show that  text editor lost its focus to console view and the button you have mentioned is not there at console view but it is there at console of eclipse on which i am writing a code.
[image]

Comment: The problem might be using a `StringBuilder` [here](https://github.com/sunilsarode/eclipse_plugin/blob/master/ccchecker/src/ccchecker/handlers/SampleHandler.java#L122) because it is [_"with no guarantee of synchronization"_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Does using a `String` or a `StringBuffer` instead work?

Comment: Does using a String or a StringBuffer instead work? - -> No

Comment: Then use a debugger. Are all lines read [here](https://github.com/sunilsarode/eclipse_plugin/blob/master/ccchecker/src/ccchecker/handlers/SampleHandler.java#L160)? If yes, where do they get lost?

Comment: @howlger no they are not getting lost (using string StringBuffer) and one more thing my development console is different and console of the eclipse on which plugin is running is different .

Comment: Do you want your plug-in to output something in the _Console_ view or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @howlger please see the edit. thanks :)

Comment: I see. Does the following answer your question? https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F

Comment: @howlger yes but i have mentioned the problem with that approach ? and also  can you please  suggest how i  can achieve that dot on gutter of the text editor.

Comment: There are two buttons in the _Console_ view toolbar to grab the focus when there is new standard and when there is new error output.

Comment: @howlger i did more edit.

Comment: The `MessageConsoleStream` has the method `setActivateOnWrite`. Did you set it to `false`?

Comment: yes it is false.

Comment: Debug your plug-in to find out at which line of code the focuse is transfered to the _Console_ view. Maybe it's before the writing.

Comment: after view.display(console); i guess , you can see my updated code on github.

Comment: You have `out.setActivateOnWrite(true);` instead of `out.setActivateOnWrite(false);`. Why do you `out.println(buffer.toString());` before `view.display(console);`? What happen if you uncomment `out.println(buffer.toString());`?

Comment: i change it to true to just check it what it does , but it was false when you asked . let me see about other things

Comment: What happen if you uncomment out.println(buffer.toString()); ,still hover changes to console and Why do you out.println(buffer.toString()); to print my error message on console ,can you suggest better thing if got my problem ,thanks lot

Comment: The idea is to create the console upfront or at that time when the first line should be prompted. As the result of this you get a `MessageConsoleStream` that can be used in a non-UI thread to print the lines sequentially (instead collection the lines in a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` first). If the focus is still lost (maybe it is only caused by displaying a console that has already some output), you can debug your code or comment out the code lines from the end to find out which line of code is causing this.

Comment: I have dropped the idea of of console , I am displaying marker. I am able to do it , but marker is also having same delay of output , you can see my code , line number is hard-coded as 16 , will change that.

Comment: Markers sound promising. Please give a self answer to your original question or delete it. If you have problems with the markers that you cannot solve yourself, ask a new question with an as small as possible example. Make sure to use the UI thread only when necessary. The long-running computations should be done in a non-UI thread and, if possible, already while reading the lines (when something happens it doesn't feel so slow).

Answer (score 0):

Following keypress method and addKeyListener is not working when i press the Ctrl+s. In order to get the save event we have to use the ICommandService with save command.

```
((StyledText) editor.getAdapter(Control.class)).addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                if (((keyEvent.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (keyEvent.keyCode == 's')) {
                    // System.out.println("From Display I am the Key down !!" + keyEvent.keyCode);
                    Job job = new Job("My job") {

                        @Override
                        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            StringBuilder builder = runCCChecker(path);

                            syncWithUi(builder);
                            return Status.OK_STATUS;
                        }

                    };

                    job.setUser(true);
                    job.schedule();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
```

In order to show the warning at each line I am using IMarker interface.
In order to run my tool only on current active file of eclipse editor on which I am firing save command , I am using IPartService service.

following is the link of my code

https://github.com/sunilsarode/eclipse_plugin/blob/master/ccchecker/src/ccchecker/handlers/SampleHandler.java

It is working fine. If anybody find any issue please let me know.